# How can I get section of my armature's bones to trail behind when moving?

Tags: animation, armature, rigging, bones

I've got a dragon armature and I'd like to have all the bones of his tail just flow behind him as he flies, without me having to position all the bones by hand along his flight path. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8772/599

Comment: You mean the chain straight following the dragons motion path or using softbody physics like gandalf3 suggests?